# iOS - If passed the bottom of the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I created a simple app that fall down an image, that's great but my problem is when it fall down it's not repeating after searching I found a to repeat it, but I want to know how to check if the image is at the bottom of the screen repeat falling. here is my code

in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
NSTimer *moveit;
IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
}
```

in .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    moveit = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.005 target:self selector:@selector(fallThei) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)fallThei{
img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x, img.center.y +9);
}
```

and the repeat code is

```
img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x, -img.frame.size.height + img.frame.size.height/2);
```

So how to check if the image at the bottom then do something? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you never do any checks to see if it is at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: put some checking such as if (img.frame.origin.x == ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)fallThei {
    if (img.center.y >= [[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]size].height) {
        img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x,0);
    } else {
        img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x,img.center.y + 9);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code it shows me an error "No member named 'height' in 'struct CGRect'"

Comment: Thank you!! That helped me and after searching I found the way to fix that problem here is the way I fixed that error `    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    if (down.center.y >= screenHeight) {
        down.center = CGPointMake(down.center.x,0);
    } else {
        down.center = CGPointMake(down.center.x,down.center.y + 9);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Add test in fallThei:

```
if(img.center.y + 9 >= screen_height + img.frame.size.height/2)
{
    img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x, -img.frame.size.height/2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there is anyway to know the screen height automatic?

Comment: Yes, with [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].height